# How to create dynamic drop down lists using combo boxes? VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a 3 layer combo box drop down on one of my sheets (not in a form).

I achieved this using data validation and named ranges but the drop down arrow only appears when you click on the box which is annoying and I want this tool to be as intuitive as possible for the users.

I have found examples of 2 layer combo boxes using switch cases which I can kind of follow but the next layer is hurting my head.

```
Layer 1 - Route (30 Values)
Layer 2 - Conveyor Number (5-10 Values per Route)
Layer 3 - Record Reference (4-20 Values per Conveyor Number)
```

I want to read the values from the combo boxes and pass to various command buttons on the sheet.

If there is an easy way of doing this rather than writing out many switch cases that would be great

I have included an image of Route 1 to give context and an image of my dashboard.

[image]

I think I need to use an active x combo box to get it to work. I also want to the drop down to be located on sheet.

I have data I want to list available in a few different formats. I have in one big list (extract shown below)

[image]

I also have in named ranged (extract shown below)

[image]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: How would even the most perfect computer be able to address this without 30/5-10/4-20 switch statements based on your projected results? You might need a dynamic named range...

Comment: I started with named ranges and data validation lists which works but its not user friendly with the drop down arrow only appearing when you click on the cell containing the list.

Ive tried a few pieces of code but not got anything to work . I initially tried switch cases but couldnt figure out the third layer

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to find a way of creating a 3 layer, dynamic combo box drop down list. It may not be pretty and there will be some inefficiencies in my code but I'm still learning this stuff.

Heres my code:

To populate layer 1 drop down list as drop down is clicked for 1st time.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "R1"
        .AddItem "R2"
        .AddItem "R3"
        .AddItem "R4"
        .AddItem "R5"
        .AddItem "R6"
        .AddItem "R7"
        .AddItem "R8"
        .AddItem "R9"
        .AddItem "R10"
        .AddItem "R11"
        .AddItem "R12"
        .AddItem "R13"
        .AddItem "R14"
        .AddItem "R15"
        .AddItem "R16"
        .AddItem "R17"
        .AddItem "R18"
        .AddItem "R19"
        .AddItem "R20"
        .AddItem "R21"
        .AddItem "R22"
        .AddItem "R23"
        .AddItem "R24"
        .AddItem "R25"
        .AddItem "R26"
        .AddItem "R27"
        .AddItem "R28"
        .AddItem "R29"
        .AddItem "R30"
        
End With

End Sub
```

Top populate layer 2 after layer 1 has been selected.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim Route As Integer
Dim Conveyor As Variant
Dim RouteSelect As Variant
Dim N As Integer

ComboBox2 = ""
ComboBox3 = ""
Do While ComboBox2.ListCount > 0
    ComboBox2.RemoveItem (0)
Loop

Do While ComboBox3.ListCount > 0
    ComboBox3.RemoveItem (0)
Loop

ComboBox2.Clear
ComboBox3.Clear

Set tbl2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AllRoutes").ListObjects("AllRoutesTable")

RouteSelect = ComboBox1.Value

RouteSelect = Mid(RouteSelect, 2)


For N = 1 To (tbl2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)

Route = tbl2.DataBodyRange(N, 1).Value

Conveyor = tbl2.DataBodyRange(N, 2).Value

If RouteSelect = Route Then

If Conveyor <> ConveyorLast Then
With ComboBox2
        .AddItem Conveyor
End With

End If
End If

ConveyorLast = Conveyor

Next


End Sub
```

To populate layer 3 after layer 2 has been selected.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim Route As Integer
Dim Conveyor As Variant
Dim RecordReference As Variant
Dim N As Integer

ComboBox3 = ""

Do While ComboBox3.ListCount > 0
    ComboBox3.RemoveItem (0)
Loop

Set tbl2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AllRoutes").ListObjects("AllRoutesTable")

ConveyorSelect = ComboBox2.Value

For N = 1 To (tbl2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)

Conveyor = tbl2.DataBodyRange(N, 2).Value

RecordReference = tbl2.DataBodyRange(N, 3).Value

If ConveyorSelect = Conveyor Then


With ComboBox3
        .AddItem RecordReference
End With

End If
Next


End Sub
```

I have essentially made code that loops through the big list I have shown in my original question and looks for which rows contain the wanted information.

Hope this helps someone.

Any code improvement suggestions welcome